# Is it possible to avoid CSS3-Pretag?

Tags: html, css

Ist it possible to avoid the CSS3-Pretag (-webkit-, -ms-, -o-) to keep the source code short and easy, because I use a lot of CSS3 on my website.

For example:

```
.scroll-up:hover:before {
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 0.65s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-name: scrollUp;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.65s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-name: scrollUp;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
    -ms-animation-duration: 0.65s;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -ms-animation-name: scrollUp;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -o-animation-delay: 0s;
    -o-animation-duration: 0.65s;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -o-animation-name: scrollUp;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

Comment: [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/)

Comment: Use [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) and SASS. It will take a bit of work to set up but you will be very pleased once you decide to go that route because it makes maintenance much easier.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748512/dynamic-css3-prefix-user-agent-detection/3748535#3748535

Answer (score 0):

If the vendor prefixes are required for your target browser range, then no - you must include them.

You can use preproccessors like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) and libraries like [Bourbon](http://bourbon.io/) to simplify your working code, or use a post proccessor like [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) or [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) to adjust your code after you've written it.

You can use http://caniuse.com/ to check if you really need the prefixes or not, as well as compatibility tables on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS).